# Scanning and printing char variables in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Why is printing `x` is always equal to zero?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char num, x, nnum, y = 0;
    printf("please enter the number of bits u want to clear \n");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    printf("%d%d", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to put them separately but after taking a variable from `y` the `x` becomes a zero.
I know that they will store eventually in the stack and every `char` is 1 byte, so when printing them 
they should both have the value that I put in it.

Comment: You are using the wrong format in the calls to `scanf()`.  You get undefined behaviour in the form of overwriting.

Comment: Why don't you make `x` and `y` be of type `int`?  Then `%d` will work as you expect, and you won't have to muck around with `%hhu`.

Comment: why is there an undefined behavior i am trying to make it taking less space as possible @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You tell `scanf()` that you're providing pointers to 4-byte (probably) integers; you provide it with pointers to 1-byte characters.  It's going to take you at your word.  On some systems, the code might crash; on others, it will be slow and will write over data that was not intended to be written.  The behaviour is undefined so both of those are valid reactions,

Comment: now i think i can tell that the first scan if will point to the address of x (but will alow to write for a 4bytes) 
and the second will point to the second address address of which is y and will allow it write for a 4byes (untill now every thing is good ) 
if i put x = 7 and y = 7 which doesnt exceed the first byte it will also give me wrong output of x

Comment: Consider this code: `char c; int i; memcpy(&c, &i, 4);`.  Do you see why this not only won't work, but will break things rather badly?  That's roughly what happens inside `scanf` when you write scanf("%d", &c)` where `c` is a `char`.

Comment: so if i want to store integer number in 8bits to save some memory what should i do 
i trying uint8_t but i still does not work idk why 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main(){ uint8_t xx ; 
uint8_t yy ; 
 unsigned char num , x, nnum , y = 0 ;
 printf("please enter the number of bits u want to clear \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&xx,&yy);
    printf("%d%d",xx,yy);
 return 0 ;  
}

Comment: 1. For individual variables like `x` and `y`, using something smaller than `int` will *not* save memory.  So you're going to a lot of trouble for no real effect. 2. If `x` and `y` are in fact `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, you can scan them with "%hhu` or `"%"SCNu8`, as we've been telling you.  (I know you tried it and it didn't work.  Try again.)

Comment: Or you could read strings, and convert to `x` and `y` by calling `atoi` (or `strtoul`).

Comment: In the comment where you wrote "idk why", you're still trying to use `%d` to read `uint8_t`.  Are you not paying attention, or what?

Comment: -why for individual variables like x and y i can not use smaller than int  ?
-for what variables i can use something smaller than int? 
so with uint8_t i can not use %d i should use %hhu ?

Comment: sir i replaced all %d with %hhu and it did not work 
did u tried it and worked for u ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you forgot to enable a good set of warnings.  For GCC, I recommend `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings` as a minimum; consider also `-Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` for identifying some other common mistakes.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, it's possible that your system does not support `%hhu`.  It's also possible it does not support `SNCu8 ` and the rest.  Or it's possible that you're making mistakes when you try to use them, and they'd work just fine if you used them properly.  It's hard to say.  Again I urge you: Just change `x` and `y` to be `int`, and move on.  (Those six bytes you think you might save are simply not worth all this trouble.)

Answer (score 3):

In your code,

```
 scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
```

is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The conversion specifier and the supplied arguments do not match. With `scanf()` family, `%d` expects an argument of type pointer to a signed integer, whereas you are supplying a pointer to an unsigned `char`.

You need to use

```
 scanf("%hhu%hhu",&x,&y);
```

Comment: it works when i i use one variable

Comment: @AliIbrahim Well, it _seems_ to work. that's the beauty of undefined behavior. Read the link in my answer.

Comment: i also tried  scanf("%hhu%hhu",&x,&y);
and still not working x will be a zero

Comment: @AliIbrahim Did you change the printf, too?

Comment: no i will do it now

Comment: unsigned char num , x, nnum , y = 0 ;
 printf("please enter the number of bits u want to clear \n");
      scanf("%hhu%hhu",&x,&y);

    printf("%hhu%hhu",x,y);

Comment: not working + i have never seen hhu b4 i really wanna understand what is wrong with %d that tell the compiler that the number the user will enter is an integer not a character thats it and char variable is used to put it in 1byte storage element

Comment: @AliIbrahim for scanf - you really need to match the conversion specification. the compiled code has no check about the size of the argument provided to scanf(), so it will try to scan an store an `int` value into a `char`, causing overflow and UB. for printf(), it will undergo default promotion.

Comment: i am not converting the value that the user will enter 
the user will enter a number and i will put this number in a 8bit char variable thats it

Comment: @AliIbrahim You can not use `scanf`.  `scanf` is an old-school function, and you have to follow the rules very carefully when you use it.  It sounds like you are not interested in following rules carefully; it sounds like you just want things to work the way you think they should work.  That's fine, *but* it means that you will never e able to call `scanf` successfully.  It is not a good match for your style of programming.

Comment: mmm i really misunderstanding something here 
what u mean that i can use scanf to take integer numbers and putting them to char variables ?

Comment: @AliIbrahim: The `hh` modifier was added in C99; there's a chance that your C library doesn't support it.  If that's the case, you'll need to read the values into a integer and assign the result to the character variables (after checking that the input worked — that `scanf()` returns `2`).

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier for a char is %c. Using %d leads to undefined behavior (overwrites the next variable on the stack).

If you want an 8bit unsigned integer then use uint8_t (stdint.h) and the SCNu8 and PRIu8 macros from inttypes.h.

Comment: i have seen alot of codes assigning integer numbers to  a char variables

Comment: the compile will convert the number to a binary then putting it in char (for example i enter 7 then 7 ) the compiler will convert the first seven to 00000111 and the second one then putting them to there variables

Comment: The problem isn't putting integers into a char variable. It's that what a char is differs between systems and the format specifier for an integer in a char differs as well. The uint8_t, SCNu8 and PRIu8 will give you the right thing or not exist (unlikely). Using char will give you undefined behavior even if you get the format string right for some systems.

Comment: what did u mean is 
scanf("%d",&should be integer variable not a char var. ); right ?
i have seen some programmers doing it ?

Comment: Not just an integer. %d has to be an integer of the right size, an int will always work. A char might work, e.g. on a DSP that only has 16bit integers and chars. It won't work on x86/amd64.

Comment: actually i put an integer with right size (7) and it did not work 
so  i make rule in my mind not to use integers with char types and always use uint8_t but sadly it didnot work too idk why 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
int main(){ uint8_t xx ; 
uint8_t yy ; 
 unsigned char num , x, nnum , y = 0 ;
 printf("please enter the number of bits u want to clear \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&xx,&yy);
    printf("%d%d",xx,yy);
 return 0 ;  
}

Comment: Because %d is still the wrong format specifier. SCNu8 and PRNu8 as said.

Comment: i kindda start to understand this dilemma 
because of i edit the int variable to make it 8bit 
it gives me error because %d works with int variables with the right storage bits 
thats ok but that also means that SCNu8 will not work also 
and what uint8_t work with if they can not work with %d

Comment: @AliIbrahim Yes, of course you can say `c = i` and `i = c`, where `i` is an `int` and `c` is a `char`.  What you need to understand here is that *`scanf` and `printf` are different*.  Those rules do not apply.  A completely ddifferent set of rules applies.

Comment: SNCu8 and PRIu8 will work with unit8_t and is only speficied to work with uint8_t. They go together, you can't use only half of them.

Comment: i can not find anything about SNCu8 and PRIu8 
do u have a link to study them and then try again with my code ?

Comment: @Goswin - the format specifier for *decimal* conversion to `unsigned char` is `%hhu` - the `%c` reads a *single character* rather than a decimal number.  With that fixed, this would become a fine answer.

Answer (score -1):

The data type is char, so basically the scanf for the char is %c. Either you will seperate variables of it. If your x is a character then you would need to seperate into the next line. The scanf for integer is a %d.

Comment: The format specifier for *decimal* conversion to `unsigned char` is `%hhu` - the `%c` reads a *single character* rather than a decimal number.